# Можно ли сделать компоновку объектов в Qt Designer такую же, как в Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt-designer

[image: В Qt Creator есть возможность сделать объекты разных размеров]
[image: И при растягивании окна объекты будут растягиваться вместе с ним]
[image: В Qt Designer при расстановке компоновщиком при растягивании окна]
[image: Объекты остаются на своём месте]
Как сделать компоновщик таким же, как в Qt Creator?

Answer (score 0):

Что-то вопрос не понятный. Qt Designer - фрейм для верстки, Qt Creator - основное рабочее окно. Qt Designer просто собирает всё в XML файл и дальше предоставляет доступы из Creator. В Qt Designer есть такие же объекты Layout's